# Ghost Records and MS Sql Express size limit

Tags: sql-server

Consider we have an MS SQL Express database that has grown up to almost 10 Gb. And consider we have a big table with a clusterred index in it.

Now we want to free some space by deleting some rows from that table. After delete db size remains the same as it was and rows become ghost records.

The question is what will happen to those GRs if db size will reach a limit of 10 GB? Will they be cleaned or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will not be automatically cleaned. The best option is to use

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> REBUILD
```

to get rid of all artefacts.

Answer (score 0):

Execute following command and check the Ghost_Record_Count and Version_Ghost_Record_Count columns. If this is high (several million in some cases), then you’ve most probably got a ghost record cleanup issue

```
Select * from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(<dbname>),<ObjectID>,NULL,NULL,’DETAILED’)
```

Following command will free up ghost records

```
EXEC sp_clean_db_free_space @dbname=N’<dbname>’
```

You can use [sp_spaceused](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) to see the amount of free space in your db

Use [DBCC SHRINKDATABASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx) or [DBCC SHRINKFILE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx) to shrink data and log files for a specific database